# Good documentation for rspec-rails Request Specs (or Integration Tests)

Tags: rspec, rspec-rails

I'm looking for any documentation or reference on how to do request specs (which I've also seen called 'integration tests') with rspec and rails.

The page [here](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails) shows a snippet in the readme for "request specs" which is the sort of testing I'd like to do (full stack testing).

```
describe "widgets resource" do
  describe "GET index" do
    it "contains the widgets header" do
      get "/widgets/index"
      response.should have_selector("h1", :content => "Widgets")
    end
  end
end
```

Is there a reference for all the methods used in this style of testing, such as how to use fixtures, cookies, sessions, redirects, etc?

Actually, is there even an rdoc for the `have_selector` method used above?  I haven't been able to find an API or rdoc for this.  Maybe I'm missing something.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have_selector is part of Webrat:

http://rubydoc.info/github/brynary/webrat/master/Webrat/Matchers

Capybara provides a larger range of matchers:

http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Matchers